# the trait bound `<RuntimeApi as ConstructRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<, OpaqueExtrinsic>>` is not satisfied

Tags: relay-chain, evm, frontier

```rs
     `the trait bound` `<RuntimeApi as ConstructRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, RuntimeApi>>>::RuntimeApi: fp_rpc::ConvertTransactionRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>` is not satisfied
        --> node/service/src/lib.rs:1279:30
         |
    1279 |             polkadot_rpc::create_full(deps,subscription_executor.clone(), backend.clone()).map_err(Into::into)
         |             ------------------------- ^^^^ the trait `fp_rpc::ConvertTransactionRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>` is not implemented for `<RuntimeApi as ConstructRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, RuntimeApi>>>::RuntimeApi`
         |             |
         |             required by a bound introduced by this call
         |
    note: required by a bound in `polkadot_rpc::create_full`
        --> /Users/user/parachain/peer-polka/rpc/src/lib.rs:205:10
         |
    205  |     C::Api: fp_rpc::ConvertTransactionRuntimeApi<Block>,    
         |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `create_full`
    help: consider further restricting the associated type
         |
    910  |     OverseerGenerator: OverseerGen, <RuntimeApi as ConstructRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_service::client::client::Client<sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, LocalCallExecutor<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, sc_client_db::Backend<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>, NativeElseWasmExecutor<ExecutorDispatch>>, sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>, RuntimeApi>>>::RuntimeApi: fp_rpc::ConvertTransactionRuntimeApi<sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, OpaqueExtrinsic>>
```

I'm integrating the `Frontier` in the `Relay Chain`. But in the `service.rs` i'm facing this issue. I've already mentioned this in the runtime.

```rs
    impl fp_rpc::ConvertTransaction<opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic> for TransactionConverter {
        fn convert_transaction(
            &self,
            transaction: pallet_ethereum::Transaction,
        ) -> opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic {
            let extrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic::new_unsigned(
                pallet_ethereum::Call::<Runtime>::transact { transaction }.into(),
            );
            let encoded = extrinsic.encode();
            opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic::decode(&mut &encoded[..])
                .expect("Encoded extrinsic is always valid")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code you pasted below implements `ConvertTransaction` for a struct `TransactionConverter`. This is not what the error is for. The error specifically says that this bound doesn't exist on `C::Api` which is your `RuntimeApi`. You need to add an implementation for `fp_rpc::ConvertTransaction` in your runtime api impl :

```rust
impl_runtime_apis! {
// -- snip --
 impl fp_rpc::ConvertTransaction<opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic> for Runtime {
        fn convert_transaction(
            &self,
            transaction: pallet_ethereum::Transaction,
        ) -> opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic {
            let extrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic::new_unsigned(
                pallet_ethereum::Call::<Runtime>::transact { transaction }.into(),
            );
            let encoded = extrinsic.encode();
            opaque::UncheckedExtrinsic::decode(&mut &encoded[..])
                .expect("Encoded extrinsic is always valid")
        }
    }
} // end of impl_runtime_apis!
```

Answer (score 0):

Do add `ConvertTransaction` and `TransactionConverter` in your `runtime/lib.rs`. And check in the trait `RuntimeApiCollection` of `Node/Client/lib.rs` that you have added or not